# How can I get the xml tag name from the generated code (through XmlBeans)?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, xmlbeans

1. I had a xml file to parse.
2. I created the xsd file related to that xml file manually.
3. I created a jar file through that xsd file so that all the tags in the xml file could be       taken as interfaces
4. Now I have got a jar file in which the tags of the xml file are treated as interfaces with their respective implementation classes.
5. My problem is I want the simple xml tag names extracted out of those implementation classes or those interfaces. I am looking for some API or some other way to do it.
6. I have used XmlBeans in this process.

I hope this explains my problem appropriately. :)

Comment: "I have created a jar file through the xsd file and I have got the corresponding interfaces for all the elements in the xml file" :- thoroghly unclear to me. Can you please re-phrase or/and add some more details please ?

Comment: @Anugoonj  I have edited the post. Please have a look.